# Postgres - Why Index Only scans are required?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-indexes

I am trying to understand index only scans in Postgres. It says Index-only scans were implemented because normal indexes (secondary) does a 2-step lookup i.e. Index does not have the complete row attached to it but the row identifier (ctid), physical location on disk, so first it finds the row's physical location using the index column and then it goes to main table to get the actual row data.

Shouldn't 2nd step be faster as it involves directly going to row and getting the data or does it need to perform a sequential scan of the main table to find particular ctid, and if it can directly go the physical location of the row using ctid then why index-only scans are required ?

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't 2nd step be faster as it involves directly going to row and getting the data

For hard disk drives, going "directly" to the row requires waiting for a physical read-head arm to seek to the correct cylinder, and for the physical disk to spin to the correct offset.  And then again for the next row, and again for the row after that.

Even for solid state disks, they don't have the latency of physical movement but they are still slower than main memory or CPU cache.

Answer (score 1):

The second step may be slow only if the first step returned many-many ctid's (many results found). So index-only scans are useful when the result is really big and can be fetched directly from index without going elsewhere to get real data.

Comment: .. and the second step may be slow because of table data fragmentation (for big tables and multiple results from 1st step)

Answer (score 1):

The second step costs resources

- (maybe) feching a whole 8K page from disk
- of which (maybe) only a few bytes are needed
- allocating bufferspace for the resulting tuple
- (maybe) locking the page or tuple
- additional cleanup, afterwards